Is there a deterministic way to reboot Windows 10/11 from the login screen (if you can't see the screen)
I have a machine that sometimes boots up without activating the discrete Nvida GPU.
Thus I have a machine that's booted, running, at the login screen, but sending video to the wrong place.  A reboot fixes it.  Is there an appropriate key combination?
To activate

I'm able to press <TAB> 12 times, then return, then up arrow twice, then return.  That reboots the machine most of the time, but is fragile in case the number of users and thus the number of tab key presses changes.
But is there a better way?  Is there an equivalent of <WIN>X U U that works for the login screen?  Would Microsoft care enough to add one and how would one ask Microsoft to do so?

Windows does not have a shortcut to initiate a system reboot.

If the machine is in a network, and you have multiple, you could do something like RDP into the machine, and reboot from there, or open command prompt, runas domain/admin and do a shutdown /m:computername /r /t 0 I'd look into doing it remotely. It is even possible to RDP to a computer from your mobile phone, and rebooting then is fairly easy.
